# How can I work around the AWS Terraform provider's limit for loadbalancer configurations per ECS Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I get the following error when I attempt to create an ECS service with over 5 loadbalancer configurations. Here is my terraform:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "elastic_integrations" {
  name            = "elastic_agent"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.elastic_integrations.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.elastic_agent.arn
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  desired_count   = 1

  dynamic "load_balancer" {
    for_each = local.xxxx_mappings
    content {
      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.ecs_service[load_balancer.key].arn
      container_name   = "elastic_agent"
      container_port   = load_balancer.value
    }
  }
```

Here is the error:

```
╷
│ Error: error creating ECS service (elastic_agent): InvalidParameterException: load balancers can have at most 5 items.
│ 
│   with aws_ecs_service.elastic_integrations,
│   on main.tf line 12, in resource "aws_ecs_service" "elastic_integrations":
│   12: resource "aws_ecs_service" "elastic_integrations" {
│ 
╵
```

This issue has been mentioned before in 2020 ([see here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25306)) but was responded to as a limitation of the terraform provider for AWS. My question is, how can I work around this limitation in Terraform as I need more than 5 loadbalancer configurations for this ECS service.

And just to note, it is perfectly OK to have more than 5 loadbalancer configurations per ECS service if it's done via the AWS UI.

Comment: I don't see any way to work around it in Terraform. It looks like it was pointed out to the person that filed the bug with the core Terraform project that they needed to file the bug with the AWS Terraform Provider project instead, and as far as I can tell they never actually proceeded to do that. You should file this as a bug with the AWS Terraform Provider project.

Comment: However, according to the official documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html you can't have more than 5, so Terraform is probably just restricting you to that limit to comply with the official documentation. "For services that use an Application Load Balancer or Network Load Balancer, you cannot attach more than five target groups to a service."